# How to get key code for shift+tab in windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Hi have an windows application that should focus to previous text box with change in back color when <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: You set the Tab order. Why you need to handle shift+ tab your own?

Comment: I suspect the seemingly incongruous words "change in back color" is the -real- question here.

Answer (score 2):

```
e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab
```

in an event handler method, using an if condition maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Shift)
    {

    }
}
```